# C# HtmlNodeCollection - Find Element inside Element

Tags: c#, html

I have this code:

```
<div class="field">
    <label class="label">Email:</label>
    <div class="data">
        <a href="mailto:1111@gmail.com">1111@gmail.com</a>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="mailto:2222@gmail.com">2222@gmail.com</a>
```

So I have two email in the html page.
I want to get only the "1111@gmail.com" , I don't care about the "2222@gmail.com".
I want to find specific email so I thought to find the  tag and inside it I'll find the specific  tag.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and [Xpath](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html).

```
    var webGet=new HtmlWeb(); 
    var docMain=webget.Load("yourUrl");
    var yourEmail=docMain.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class=data]/a").Attributes["href"].Value
```

It should work